# Dont undestand why 2 of 3 slots working and the third doesnt in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i am learning Vue and i cant stiil figure out how slots work for good:
here`s a template of a component with named slots:

```
<template lang="">
  <div class="w-96 h-96 border border-solid border-black rounded-xl shadow-md">
    <div
      name="Question title"
      class="w-96 h-[30%] border border-solid border-green-500 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <h1
        class="text-xl text-center flex items-center justify-center font-bold"
      >
        <slot name="title">The Question Title</slot>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div
      name="answers-container"
      class="border border-solid border-blue-500 w-96 h-[50%] rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
    >
      The Answers:
      <button class="border-4 border-solid border-red-300">
        <slot name="answer"> </slot>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div
      name="buttons"
      class="border border-solid border-yellow-500 w-96 h-[20%] rounded-lg flex items-center justify-between px-4"
    >
      <button class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-xl">
        <slot name="1button">Default</slot>
      </button>
      <button class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-xl">
        <slot name="2button">Default</slot>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and how i try to use it:

```
<template lang="">
  <div>
    <the-question-card>
      <template #title>
        <h1>{{ currentQuestion.Question }}</h1>
      </template>
      <template #answer>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(answer, index) in currentQuestion.answers" :key="index">
            <button>
              {{ answer.answer }}
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </template>
      <template #1button><button @click="getData">load data</button> </template>
      <template #2button
        ><button @click="currentIndex++">Next</button></template
      >
    </the-question-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

2 of 3 named slots work, and the third, this, doesnt work:

```
 <template #answer>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(answer, index) in currentQuestion.answers" :key="index">
            <button>
              {{ answer.answer }}
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </template>
```

comming from this:

```
<div
      name="answers-container"
      class="border border-solid border-blue-500 w-96 h-[50%] rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
    >
      The Answers:
      <button class="border-4 border-solid border-red-300">
        <slot name="answer"> </slot>
      </button>
    </div>
```

there is one red border over all the answers instead of rendering each answer with it own red border; i dont really understand why it doesnt work; if u could provide me not only solution, but also a good explanation to this example, it would be great

it tried moving the slot in and out..

Comment: You are putting a list containing buttons inside a button - pretty sure this is invalid HTML. If you  remove the button wrapping the slot, does it change?

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar. What you shared so far is insufficient to repro. It's missing versions of used packages and how the data looks like (e.g: its structure). In short, it needs debugging details.